# Python script not able to access the directory at user home location when run using docker-compose on Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, vmware, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to open a directory from a python script running inside a docker container using docker-compose, the file is a part of an application, the setup is a following

**OS** : Ubuntu 18.04 running on VMWare.

**Application** : Running on docker on top of Ubuntu OS on VMWare.

**Setup** : application creates it's own directory with docker-compose called '/application' and there it is supposed to run a python script which is will read some files from the following directory '/home/$user/repository' inside user home folder.

**Piece of Code**

```
repo_base = '/home/vipin/repository'
repo_folder_path = os.path.join(repo_base, 'vectors', 'current')
listOfFiles = os.listdir(repo_folder_path)
```

**Error**

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vipin/repository/vectors/current'`

**I have tried running the script manually from terminal and it works completely fine, the issue only happens when I run it via docker-compose.**

**I am running docker-compose commands using sudo, have also tried running it from root user but it has no effect. Any help would be appreciated**

Comment: as I understand you do this `-v /home/$user/repository:/application` then you need to use : `repo_base = '/application'` in your code

Comment: Is the directory - `/home/vipin/repository` inside host(Ubuntu) or inside Docker container?

Comment: @Shiva: The directory is inside host.

Comment: Docker containers provide a layer of isolation, and can't directly access content on their hosts' file systems.  In this case the "host" is a VM which provides a layer of isolation, and it can't directly access content on _its_ host system.  If the user's home directory on the physical system is what's important, don't use Docker inside a VM; use a lighter-weight system like a Python virtual environment that can directly access host files.

Comment: That having been said, including the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file in the question, along with knowing how file sharing is configured on the VM, would be very helpful in trying to diagnose this further.

Comment: @DavidMaze : Finally got it to work with the suggestion from accepted answer it was infact the missing volumes mapping as you all suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers run is different namespace, which by default won't have access to host drive.
You need to use 'volumes' to be able to access host drives and mount it to containers

example:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: my_db
    #pg_hba.conf configure this file
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=me
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=nothing
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

More:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Thanks it was indeed a missing volume info :)